# Azure Mobile Services Export Module and Tables Object

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have some shared code in a file, let's called it shared.js that is "required" in the endpoints.  It looks something like below.  I can't seem to find the `tables` and `mssql` services nor any documentation on those except they are available on the `request` object.  Am I forced to pass them in or can I get to them?

`azure.tables` doesn't work nor is `tables` a global object like it would be on a table operations.   When on an api end point `request.service.tables` contains the object.  I want to perform some of these operations inside some shared code without passing them in if possible.

Exports Code:

```
var azure = require('azure');
exports.getActive = function (success, failure) {
    // azure.tables doesn't work either
    // tables no go
    tables.getTable('mytable').where({ active: true }).read(
        {
            success: function (results) {
                var result;
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    result = results[0];
                    success(result);

                } else {
                    failure("error");
                }

            },
            error: function (err) {
                failure(err);
            }
        }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting my question, I'll leave this here.  After reading more documentation I finally found the answer:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-server-scripts/#api-routes

> In this example, you must pass both a tables object and a user object
>   to the shared function. This is because shared scripts cannot access
>   the global tables object, and the user object only exists in the
>   context of a request.

In the end I modified the function:

`exports.getActive = function (tbl) {...}`